# Why is sequence prediction always the objective in RNN and LSTM like algorithms

Tags: nlp, lstm, rnn, sequence-to-sequence

The title is pretty much my question. I haven't seen any literature yet that uses a different training objective. The goal is to find the hidden states eventually, then why is it that only 1 method is so popular, and there are no others seen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sequence prediction is **not** the only objective in RNNs and LSTMs.

For instance, we have sequence classification, where the input to the RNN/LSTM is the sequence, and the output is its label; a concrete example of that is sentiment analysis, where the input is a sentence, and the output is whether the answer is positive, negative or neutral. You can see specific models and benchmark datasets at [paperswithcode](https://paperswithcode.com/area/natural-language-processing/text-classification).

Another objective is sequence tagging where, for each timestep, we output a label; an example is part-of-speech (POS) tagging, where the input is a textual sequence and the output is the POS tag each of the words in the text has. You can see specific models and benchmark datasets at [paperswithcode](https://paperswithcode.com/task/part-of-speech-tagging).